# OCAML : Converting a List (Int*Float) to a Float List

Tags: list, int, ocaml

What i wanna do is to convert a list like `[1,3.0,5,5.5,8]` to `[1.0,3.0,5.0,5.5,8.0]`.
The problem is I don't know the list, and so I can't use float_of_int, because it wont work for elements that are already floats.

Answer (score 3):

Your title says (in essence) `(int * float) list`. However your example lists (correcting for OCaml syntax) are impossible. There is no list in OCaml that contains some floats and some ints. All elements of a list must be the same type.

If you really have `(int * float) list`, they look like this:

```
[(1, 1.5); (2, 3.8); (3, 8.9)]
```

Every element is a pair with an int and a float. So it's easy to handle them all with the same code.